# Angular form data to be sent in an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, reactive

I am sending a post request to the backend with just one input field and I able to display my request in console as "request". But the backend is expecting the request to be in an array like this ["request"].

Comment: Have you tried `return this._http.post<any>(this._url, Array(userData));`

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
    this.verifyService.verify(this.hashForm.value)
```

To this:

```
    this.verifyService.verify([this.hashForm.value])
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Mathew, but it didn't work, it gives me the same output in console. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if your backend expects only `string[]` value and your form has only one input.

```
this.verifyService.verify([this.hashForm.controls.contentHash.value])
```